# Any "casual" translation for 遵命?

Tags: translation, word-choice

> 遵命

It's said from a person of lesser position to a person of higher position, ie from soldier to general.

What would be a more "casual" way of translating it into English other than "As you wish", because "as you wish" sounds like something that is said to royalty and whatnot, rather than a soldier to general (as an example).

Comment: yessir (http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yessir).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, there are plenty of "casual" translations.

In a military setting,

- "Yes, Sir."
- "Roger that."
- "Copy that."
- "Affirmative."

*Note that the later three have the same implication as that of `遵命` but is more accurately translated to `收到`

In a even less serious setting,

- "Will do."
- "Sure."

I will edit when I have thought of more.

Answer (score 5):

"at your command"

(ignore: 30 characters patch)

Answer (score 4):

In an everyday context could be something like

> "I'm on it"
>
> "Right away"

Or perhaps in a more authoritative context an example could include

> "At your service"